# Problem Loop Web Scraping With Calculation and Binding to Build Table R

Tags: r, loops, web-scraping

I'm trying to build a web scraped data table using a number ticker symbols via a query that pulls 1 year's worth of price and discount data from the host's website for a particular fund.

I have the query pages correct, but the loop that I'm trying to execute to one by one grab each company's price history and then do several pretty basic calculations with it before indexing the result to it's corresponding ticker and then binding each successive fund's results together into a larger table is hanging me up.

Here is my sample script if anyone can identify the issue and propose a solution:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(lubridate)

tickers2 <- c("PMX", "MFM", "CEF", "JLS","CXE","BHV")
tickers2 <- paste0("https://www.cefconnect.com/api/v3/pricinghistory/",tickers2,"/1Y")

lst_scraped_data <- lapply(tickers2, FUN=function(URLLink){
        url <-URLLink 
        page<-html_session(url)
        json3<-readBin(page$response$content, what="json")
        df15 <-fromJSON(json3)
        df15 <- data.frame(df15)

        #  Attempt to Manually Calculate the first tables 52 Week Values
        test4 <- xts(df15[2:4],mdy(df15$Data.PriceHistory.DataDateDisplay))
        colnames(test4) <- c("NAV Price","Discount %","Share Price")
        obs <- dim(test4)[1]

        cur <- tail(test4,n=1)

        WeekMean <- tail(apply(test4, 2, function(x){apply.rolling(x, FUN="mean", width=dim(test4)[1])}),n=1)
        WeekMean <- data.frame(round(WeekMean,digits=2))

        WeekMin <- tail(apply(test4, 2, function(x){apply.rolling(x, FUN="min", width=dim(test4)[1])}),n=1)
        WeekMin <- data.frame(round(WeekMin,digits=2))

        WeekMax <- tail(apply(test4, 2, function(x){apply.rolling(x, FUN="max", width=dim(test4)[1])}),n=1)
        WeekMax <- data.frame(round(WeekMax,digits=2))

        complete <- data.frame(rbind(cur,WeekMean,WeekMax,WeekMin))
        row.names(complete) <- c("Current","Year Avg","Year High","Year Low")

        complete2 <- data.frame(cbind(complete[,3],complete[,1],complete[,2]))
        colnames(complete2) <- c('Share_Price',"NAV","Premium/Discount_%")
        rownames(complete2)[1] <- "Current"

        Ticker <- str_replace_all(URLLink,pattern="https://www.cefconnect.com/api/v3/pricinghistory/",replacement = "")
        Ticker <- str_replace_all(URLLink,pattern="/1Y",replacement = "")
        Checker = data.frame(df15,Ticker)    
})


df13 <- do.call(rbind, lst_scraped_data)
```

Ideally the end result would look something like this for each ticker:

```
         Share_Price   NAV Premium/Discount_%  Ticker
Current        11.52 10.45              10.24  PMX
WeekMean       11.32 10.66               6.19  PMX
WeekMax        11.78 10.95              11.33  PMX
WeekMin        10.81 10.35               0.65  PMX
```

The completed table would be comprised of binding the output above for each ticker in the loop.

Comment: *larger table is hanging me up* ... this is not helpful for us. Please describe errors and/or undesired results.

Comment: Here is the error I get:  Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 251, 0.  This is running the above function with the full list of tickers.  Basically, I want to query the year's worth of data run those basic calculations on it, organize it, add an identifier for ticker it corresponds with, and then repeat the process.  Each time the process runs the result is added to a larger table which is the final output.  Thanks for your review!

Comment: For instance executing the script from url down to rownames(complete2)[1] works without issue.  I replace URL with a static url for one ticker but the loop I'd like would work down the larger list one by one.

Answer (score 1):

It is still unclear what the issue exactly is, however, maybe that will help.

The data contains dates properly formatted, using `format` can then give us the week number of a given date.

```
df15 <-fromJSON(json3)
df <- df15$Data$PriceHistory                # (json3 as in your function)
df$week <- as.integer(format(as.Date(df$DataDate), '%V'))
```

From here on now it becomes simpler to get weekly data

```
# For Example NAV and Discount weekly means, maxs, mins
means <- aggregate(df[, c("NAVData", "DiscountData")], list(df$week), mean)
maxs  <- aggregate(df[, c("NAVData", "DiscountData")], list(df$week), max)
mins  <- aggregate(df[, c("NAVData", "DiscountData")], list(df$week), min)
setNames(merge(merge(means, mins, by = 'Group.1'), maxs, by = 'Group.1'), 
         c('week','NAVMean','DiscountMean','NAVMins','DiscountMins','NAVMaxs','DiscountMaxs'))
#    week NAVMean DiscountMean NAVMins DiscountMins NAVMaxs DiscountMaxs
# 1     1 10.5350       8.2575   10.49         6.20   10.57         9.89
# 2     2 10.5080       9.8980   10.46         8.71   10.56        11.33
# 3     3 10.6540       7.4200   10.45         4.75   10.95        10.24
# ...
# 50   50 10.5300       8.3500   10.49         5.34   10.59         9.92
# 51   51 10.4340       5.5520   10.38         4.39   10.48         6.56
# 52   52 10.4825       6.7975   10.48         6.20   10.49         7.82
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Maybe this was unclear but I'm not looking for each week's Min/Max/Avg, I'm trying to build a loop that collects that table of data and then calculates the 52w Min/Max/Average and Current values for each ticker.  From there the table would be paired with its corresponding ticker and then the process would repeat itself with each successive ticker's data being added to the overall table.  Any ideas how to do that?  I appreciate your help.